# Max current for 0\$\Omega\$ resistor

Tags: resistors, maximum-ratings

What would be the max current an 0805 0Ohm 5% resistor can handle (5V-24V) ?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It would depend on the component that you chose and the information would be located on the datasheet of that component.

Comment: @Gilad You might think P = RI^2, so for R = 0 it follows that P= 0, but besides a P limit a certain resistor design also has an I limit.

Comment: 0 ohm resistors don't have a % tolerance because any percent of zero will be zero. You need to check the datasheet for max current values.

Comment: So, by your method, it would be possible to transfer 100A on a 0805... Without testing I can tell you that this is impossible. A 0Ohm resistor should be treated as a wire but since I don't know the size or thickness of the dialectic layer I can't determine what would be the maximum current.

Comment: The resistor is from the 5% "family", 125mW. The datasheet doesn't specify the maximum current for a 0Ohm resistor.

Comment: From this ref http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1509465.pdf it gives the max rating of 150V /2A for an 0805

Comment: Tnx Jim, I was looking at a part by Yageo which doesn't have this information.

Comment: How about supplying a part number and a link to the datasheet. The [Vishay D/CRCW e3 datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/427/dcrcwe3-109170.pdf) indicates"Zero-Ohm-Resistor: Rmax. = 20m ohm, Imax. at 70 °C = 2.5 A" for the 0.125W 0805 package. Current could be derated for higher temperatures using a graph in the datasheet.

Comment: part: AF0805JR-070RL

Comment: From [Yageo's datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/447/PYu-AF_51_RoHS_L_1-268224.pdf) ... for AF0805 "Zero Ohm Jumper < 0.05 Ω" ... I calculate Imax at 70 degrees C = 1.58A. Must derate for higher temperatures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well there's no such thing as a zero ohm resistor, not a room temperature anyway. If you find one call me I'll invest :)   The datasheet says 805 Jumpers are < 50m\$\Omega\$, and I don't see any quoting of 5% for that number.  Later it says it's 805 package can dissipate .125W @ 70C.   So if \$P = i^2R\$ then the max \$i\$ would be about 1.5A.  Of course you may want to de-rate that for your application.

Answer (score 0):

read the datasheet :)
they tend to range from 0.5A to 2.0A to 3.0A (in that size), which is a pretty wide range, so best to check on the specific 0-ohm links you're considering.